# Is there a convenient way to switch the default Standard Library to Custom Library during compilation?

Tags: clang

I'm looking for a way to switch the default Standard Library to a Custom Library during compilation without using external scripts.

I want to switch default Standard Library to Boost or Facebook Folly, Both seems has everything included in the default Standard Library. One caveat is that they use their own prefixes like `boost::` or `folly::` instead of `std::`

The compiler in question is clang++

I need to do this to benchmark Custom Libraries for performance reasons, but I don't want to manually refactor the whole codebase into a custom Standard Library.

I love to keep `std::` in code as it's so other developers don't get confused.

Is this possible to do in clang?

Comment: Ideally, you'd **not** have `std` prefix in the code, instead you'd have something like `stl` prefix, and `#define stl` to whatever lib provider you want to use. By the way,I am also quite skeptical about those libraries having everything included in standard library. For example, `boost` does not provide `cout`, and this is just random example.

Comment: With all due respect, if it says `std::` and that _doesn't_ mean standard library, I wouldn't want anything to do with your source code.

Comment: A quick question. Can `boost::shared_ptr` be easily swapped out for `std::shared_ptr` or `folly::shared_ptr`and so on for other constructs? If yes, then one can just have `#define std boost` etc. based on compiler flags. If no, well...

Comment: If its just for profiling, and wont be included in actual production code, `#define std whatever_library_you_want_to_use`

Comment: @SergeyA I don't use `using namespace std`.

Comment: It should be noted that both `boost` and `folly` **require** a working standard library to operate correctly.  And they cannot use themselves as such.

Comment: @NathanOliver I worked on the systems which do that (actually, well-known US company). It is a pure nightmare.

Comment: @Zoso I'm aware some stuff are not included. It would be great if there is a way to automatically fallback to std in that cases..

Comment: `using namespace std;` is itself a statement. You're using it or you aren't. You're confused about what's being said.

Comment: @jeffbRTC if you want to easily swap different libraries, you should not be using `std::vector`. Instead, you want to be using `stl::vector`, with `stl` defined to whatever vector library prefix you might want to use.

Comment: @SergeyA It's not just vector, I want to switch everything.

Comment: other developer will get confused when `std::vector` is not `std::vector` but something else. Its not quite clear what you want to do. Can you give a concrete example? As others have said, neither `boost` nor `folly` are "custom standard libraries"

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 The underlaying implementation doesn't matter because they knew `std::`  implementation varies from compiler to compiler. I want to do this based on that philosophy.

Comment: sorry I dont understand, you can already compile the same code that uses `std::vector` with different compilers to get different implementations

Comment: It is still not clear what you want to do. If you have a true alternative STL implementation, which is defining the names in `std` namespace as required by standard, than you need to tell compiler to use this library. clang can be configured to use either libstdc++ or libc++, for example.

Comment: why make that your "philosphy" when it isnt true? `boost` has a lot of replacements for the standard libary, but it is not an implementation of the standard library. The point is that you need to pick what you want, you cant get it all. You cant replace `std::` with `boost::` everywehre

Comment: There is a huge difference between knowing you're using different _implementations_ of the standard library versus knowing you're using the standard library at all.  If you want to measure performance of specific parts of a library, I suggest set up proper performance tests to compare.  You should avoid trying to pretend that the standard library is something else.

Comment: `folly` does not have everything from the standard library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a namespace `notstd`, or some other clear name that evokes the standard library without claiming to be it.

In `notstd`, include copious `template<class...Ts>using shared_ptr=WHICH_STL::shared_ptr<Ts...>;`

Search and replace `std::shared_ptr` with `notstd::shared_ptr`, and `#include <memory>` with `#include <notstd/memory>`.

This is work.

Note that the same named construct may differ in details between `std`, `folly` and `boost`.

Changing `std` to refer to something besides `std` is going to make your program ill-formed, no diagnostic required, with near 100% certainty.

Comment: Can I do this with a compiler plugin? I think manually replacing can have false positives.

Comment: @jeffbRTC If you are doing it piece by piece, text based search is going to be 99%+ accurate for `std::shared_ptr` to `notstd::shared_ptr`.  Then the compiler will catch any errors you make.  There may be refactoring tools that do this for you, but I am unaware of any that would be as easy as "search and replace here".  I have seen people write scripts that rely on parsing C++ and modifying the code based on that parse, but it was for significantly more complex situations than this.

Comment: But manual replacement takes a lot of time in a large code base and plus I want to benchmark diff libs.

Comment: @jeff once the above is done, you can swap out one type for another library in one spot.  And benchmark.  I get tou want this to be free, it won't be.  The different libraries will have different APIs and incompatibilities and will require manual work anyhow.

Comment: I totally missed your notstd part. Can you add a code for that namespace?

It's very unclear (but clear some parts). 

`#include <notstd/memory>` how does this works? There is no compiled lib called notstd only namespace. How does it include memory??

Comment: You write it.  It has using declarations.

Comment: I don't understand. How does compiler find `#include <notstd/memory>` when there is no library called notstd in the Linux Lib paths? I haven't seen anything like this before.

Comment: @jeffbrtc you create a directory called `notstd`.  In it you make a file called `memory`.  You tell the compiler to add the root of notstd to the header file search path.  No offence, but if this confuses you, you certainly shouldn't be replacing large pieces of C++ libraries with others, because this is not a complex part of the C++ toolchain.  Replacing one library with another the way you are asking is going to run into a lot more complex issues than "make a header file". You probably lack the context to understand how much at your level of experience. (or maybe I am the fool, that happens)

Comment: Ok. So it's an empty file, yes?